# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space importing a serialized file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, weka

When I try to import in my main a serialized file the program stop working and throws: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.
I know that this exception can be thrown because of a lack of memory but I don't think this is the reason in this case.
In my pc I have 8gb of RAM. This is the file .ini of Eclipse:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx7500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

I noticed that although eclipse could use almost all the memory of my pc, when this error occurs, the RAM used is just 5Gb approximately.
The file I'm trying to import is of 500Mb. The same program worked for many files of 350Mb.
This is the line of code where the program crush, and is the first line of my program:

```
Classifier cls1 = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("C:\\Users\\.....\\FileToImport.model");
```

For who knows, i'm using the Weka library.
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Do you need complete content in single load?

Comment: I can't understand well what you mean, but yes I should load the file and the use cls1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'eclipse.ini' file sets the memory for Eclipse itself **not** your program.

To set the memory for your program open the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog. Find your program in the Java Application section and specify the -Xmx option you want in the 'Arguments > VM arguments' section.

Comment: Thank you! In all the material i found they suggest to modify file .ini and not also the arguments of VM